# Alfred 2 fails to launch after upgrade to Yosemite

Tags: crash, macos, alfred, applications

I just upgraded to Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10 and Alfred 2 fails to launch.

In Activity Monitor, it reports that it is not responding, and the only thing I can do is Force Quit it.

Console doesn't report any messages except the kill message from my force quit.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Alfred myself so I can't give a specific answer.

Something I would try though is using `opensnoop` to see if I can work out where it is failing.

If you type `sudo opensnoop | grep alfred` into a Terminal it'll show you all the files that Alfred is touching. That might help you identify where it is crashing, for example if it is a corrupt plist file.

Comment: All that `opensnoop` reported was the following `502   1059 BetterTouchTool  30 /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/alfred/2.3_264/Alfred 2.app/Contents/PkgInfo`

Comment: That is weird. I just installed Alfred through `brew cask install alfred`, ran it a couple of times, then launched it again with `sudo opensnoop | grep alfred` and it spit out all kinds of stuff. Maybe check your brew installation with `brew update && brew doctor`, you'll get a warning about Xcode being out of date as Apple haven't posted 6.1 to the App Store yet, but it may throw up other more specific errors.

Comment: I may just `brew cask uninstall alfred` then `brew cask install alfred` and see what happens. It's 3am for me and I'm pooped...so it will have to wait till the morning (or more accurately, a little later in the morning).

Comment: Or just be patient!!! I guess that since Alfred hooks into search results indexed by Spotlight and Spotlight was indexing 12Tb of HD, it was slowing things down. Alfred is working now.

Comment: I uprooted your answer because, although it didn't solve my issue, the `opensnoop` cli app was a nice discovery for me, and can come in handy when I have other problems. Thank you.